# TypeError: 'UniqueConstraint' object is not iterable in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I set multiple unique fields with `UniqueConstraint`:

```
class Meta:
    constraints = (models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['student', 'classroom', 'code'], name='student_classroom_code'))
```

and run `python manage.py makemigrations` Raise this error:

```
TypeError: 'UniqueConstraint' object is not iterable
```

**What is wrong with this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error simply means that it is not iterable. Try to define it like this

For example

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields['app_uuid', 'version_code'], name='unique appversion')]
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to assign iterable to the constraints. You are missing `,` in `(models.UniqueConstraint(...),)`, which means you are assigning `models.UniqueConstraint` instance instead of tuple.

```
class Meta:
    constraints = (models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['student', 'classroom', 'code'], name='student_classroom_code'),)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python tuples need at least one `,` before closing. If you dont specify this `,`, the interpreter take it for a group and the type will be the var inside the parenthesis

Example:

```
t = ('i am a tuple',)         # this is good
t = ('i am not a tuple')      # this is bad
```